# Content cut vertically within flex-box

Tags: css, tailwind-css

[image: Cut content]

Using tailwind here, but it should be readable, also removed all unnecessary classes.

```
<div class="h-full min-h-full w-full left-0 top-0 fixed flex tw-box-border justify-center items-center overflow-y-auto min-h-250" style="z-index: 99999">
    <div class="w-800 min-w-250 max-w-full flex-col items-center justify-center">
        CONTENT HERE
    </div>
</div>
```

I got a fixed wrapper and a modal within. On small screens, even with `overflow-y: auto`, the content overlaps the wrapper on the vertical axis and is hidden. I guess it's a problem with the flex property. Read about it [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47594060/flex-children-are-being-cut-off-on-smaller-screens) but couldn't fix it. Any suggestions?

Comment: I can't tell from the image what the issue is. Please share a reproducible example.

Comment: @TimR The problem is that the content gets cut vertically when reducing the screen size. It gets pushed out top the same amount it ads overflow on the bottom.

Comment: Due to `fixed` with `items-center`

Comment: @TimR Also with `absolute` the problem exists. But how to fix this? One way would be to create a relative element inside the wrapper and position the child absolute. But that seems ugly.

Answer (score 0):

All right, thanks to @Asons answer on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48876120/flexbox-align-items-overflow-text-get-cuts-off-at-top) it seems content always will be cut of using `align-items: center;`. So some "solution" will be using media-queries aligning the content to `start` to prevent this behavior on smaller screens.